# How to populate a ComboBox in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I'm trying to populate a `ComboBox` with a pair of **String, Value**. I did it in code behind like this:

```cs
listCombos = new List<ComboBoxItem>();
item = new ComboBoxItem { Text = Cultures.Resources.Off, Value = "Off" };
listCombos.Add(item);
item = new ComboBoxItem { Text = Cultures.Resources.Low, Value = "Low" };
listCombos.Add(item);
item = new ComboBoxItem { Text = Cultures.Resources.Medium, Value = "Medium" };
listCombos.Add(item);
item = new ComboBoxItem { Text = Cultures.Resources.High, Value = "High" };
listCombos.Add(item);
combo.ItemsSource = listCombos;
```

ComboBoxItem:

```cs
public class ComboBoxItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm inserting the `Text` value using my `ResourceDictionary`. But if I do it in this way, when I change language at runtime, the `ComboBox` content doesn't.

So I wanted to try to fill my `ComboBox` at the design (at XAML).

So my question is: how can I fill my `ComboBox` with a pair **Text, Value** like above?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will use `Tag`, not `Value` in xaml.
This would be like this:

```
<ComboBox>
     <ComboBoxItem Tag="L" IsSelected="True">Low</ComboBoxItem>
     <ComboBoxItem Tag="H">High</ComboBoxItem>
     <ComboBoxItem Tag="M">Medium</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: That was exactly the solution! Thanks! :)